# error while plotting histogram with PIL,plt , numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, histogram

I tried to draw the hist in between the color ranges but it's showing the jpeg image file is not subscriptable

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(r"C:/Users/Atharva/Downloads/secimg.jpg")
img.thumbnail((64,64),Image.ANTIALIAS) #Image.ANTIALIAS
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal')
```

the output was
[![the image plotted is][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5yAT.png

After that I tried to draw a histogram and there is that error what should I do to plot the hist

```
himplot = img[:,:,0]
plt.hist(himplot.ravel(), bins=256, range=(0, 251), fc='k', ec='k')
```

error is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-08f1ac3d88ff> in <module>
      1 # plt.hist(img.ravel(), bins = 256,range(50,225),fc='k',ec='k')
----> 2 himplot = img[:,:,0]
      3 plt.hist(himplot.ravel(), bins=256, range=(0, 251), fc='k', ec='k')

TypeError: 'JpegImageFile' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: You probably need to convert the object to Numpy before trying to `img[:, :, 0]`. Try adding `img=np.array(img)` before the line that throws the error.

Comment: Yup it worked Ananda the array should be converted to NumPy before plotting the histogram

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help @ananda
I finally able to plot the histogram the problem was I did not convert the array to NumPy array the final code is

```
img = np.array(img)
himplot = img[:,:,0]
plt.hist(himplot.ravel(), bins=256, range=(0, 251), fc='k', ec='k')
```

and output is

```
(array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,
         2.,  3.,  3.,  2.,  5.,  8., 11.,  2.,  6.,  4., 10.,  6.,  0.,
         3.,  5.,  4., 10., 11.,  9.,  4.,  8.,  7., 10., 12.,  7., 14.,
        11., 10.,  7.,  8., 14.,  9., 17., 16., 18., 19., 11., 24., 17.,
        25., 24., 38., 29., 38., 29., 27., 28., 18., 27., 23., 29., 33.,
        50., 64., 57., 57., 55., 52., 52., 45., 44., 45., 47.,  0., 50.,
        42., 36., 40., 47., 37., 28., 22., 41., 31., 30., 38., 35., 24.,
        16., 17., 14., 20., 23., 13., 16., 15., 12., 15., 11., 16., 16.,
        19.,  8.,  9., 13., 13., 20., 11.,  9., 10.,  5., 13., 12.,  7.,
         4.,  7.,  6.,  6.,  5.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  2.,  6.,  0.,  7.,  4.,
        12.,  5., 10., 13.,  8.,  4.,  8.,  8.,  3.,  7.,  9., 12., 14.,
         7.,  7.,  6.,  9., 11., 11.,  6.,  6., 11.,  9., 13.,  7., 12.,
         8., 10., 14., 11., 13.,  6.,  8., 10.,  9.,  7., 13., 11.,  9.,
        10., 13., 10.,  8.,  5.,  5., 13., 10., 10.,  0.,  7.,  7.,  8.,
        13., 12., 11.,  8.,  9.,  8., 11.,  9.,  8.,  5.,  5.,  7.,  4.,
         5.,  6.,  5.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  4.,  1.,  1.,
         0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]),
 array([  0.        ,   0.98046875,   1.9609375 ,   2.94140625,
          3.921875  ,   4.90234375,   5.8828125 ,   6.86328125,
          7.84375   ,   8.82421875,   9.8046875 ,  10.78515625,
         11.765625  ,  12.74609375,  13.7265625 ,  14.70703125,
         15.6875    ,  16.66796875,  17.6484375 ,  18.62890625,
         19.609375  ,  20.58984375,  21.5703125 ,  22.55078125,
         23.53125   ,  24.51171875,  25.4921875 ,  26.47265625,
         27.453125  ,  28.43359375,  29.4140625 ,  30.39453125,
         31.375     ,  32.35546875,  33.3359375 ,  34.31640625,
         35.296875  ,  36.27734375,  37.2578125 ,  38.23828125,
         39.21875   ,  40.19921875,  41.1796875 ,  42.16015625,
         43.140625  ,  44.12109375,  45.1015625 ,  46.08203125,
         47.0625    ,  48.04296875,  49.0234375 ,  50.00390625,
         50.984375  ,  51.96484375,  52.9453125 ,  53.92578125,
         54.90625   ,  55.88671875,  56.8671875 ,  57.84765625,
         58.828125  ,  59.80859375,  60.7890625 ,  61.76953125,
         62.75      ,  63.73046875,  64.7109375 ,  65.69140625,
         66.671875  ,  67.65234375,  68.6328125 ,  69.61328125,
         70.59375   ,  71.57421875,  72.5546875 ,  73.53515625,
         74.515625  ,  75.49609375,  76.4765625 ,  77.45703125,
         78.4375    ,  79.41796875,  80.3984375 ,  81.37890625,
         82.359375  ,  83.33984375,  84.3203125 ,  85.30078125,
         86.28125   ,  87.26171875,  88.2421875 ,  89.22265625,
         90.203125  ,  91.18359375,  92.1640625 ,  93.14453125,
         94.125     ,  95.10546875,  96.0859375 ,  97.06640625,
         98.046875  ,  99.02734375, 100.0078125 , 100.98828125,
        101.96875   , 102.94921875, 103.9296875 , 104.91015625,
        105.890625  , 106.87109375, 107.8515625 , 108.83203125,
        109.8125    , 110.79296875, 111.7734375 , 112.75390625,
        113.734375  , 114.71484375, 115.6953125 , 116.67578125,
        117.65625   , 118.63671875, 119.6171875 , 120.59765625,
        121.578125  , 122.55859375, 123.5390625 , 124.51953125,
        125.5       , 126.48046875, 127.4609375 , 128.44140625,
        129.421875  , 130.40234375, 131.3828125 , 132.36328125,
        133.34375   , 134.32421875, 135.3046875 , 136.28515625,
        137.265625  , 138.24609375, 139.2265625 , 140.20703125,
        141.1875    , 142.16796875, 143.1484375 , 144.12890625,
        145.109375  , 146.08984375, 147.0703125 , 148.05078125,
        149.03125   , 150.01171875, 150.9921875 , 151.97265625,
        152.953125  , 153.93359375, 154.9140625 , 155.89453125,
        156.875     , 157.85546875, 158.8359375 , 159.81640625,
        160.796875  , 161.77734375, 162.7578125 , 163.73828125,
        164.71875   , 165.69921875, 166.6796875 , 167.66015625,
        168.640625  , 169.62109375, 170.6015625 , 171.58203125,
        172.5625    , 173.54296875, 174.5234375 , 175.50390625,
        176.484375  , 177.46484375, 178.4453125 , 179.42578125,
        180.40625   , 181.38671875, 182.3671875 , 183.34765625,
        184.328125  , 185.30859375, 186.2890625 , 187.26953125,
        188.25      , 189.23046875, 190.2109375 , 191.19140625,
        192.171875  , 193.15234375, 194.1328125 , 195.11328125,
        196.09375   , 197.07421875, 198.0546875 , 199.03515625,
        200.015625  , 200.99609375, 201.9765625 , 202.95703125,
        203.9375    , 204.91796875, 205.8984375 , 206.87890625,
        207.859375  , 208.83984375, 209.8203125 , 210.80078125,
        211.78125   , 212.76171875, 213.7421875 , 214.72265625,
        215.703125  , 216.68359375, 217.6640625 , 218.64453125,
        219.625     , 220.60546875, 221.5859375 , 222.56640625,
        223.546875  , 224.52734375, 225.5078125 , 226.48828125,
        227.46875   , 228.44921875, 229.4296875 , 230.41015625,
        231.390625  , 232.37109375, 233.3515625 , 234.33203125,
        235.3125    , 236.29296875, 237.2734375 , 238.25390625,
        239.234375  , 240.21484375, 241.1953125 , 242.17578125,
        243.15625   , 244.13671875, 245.1171875 , 246.09765625,
        247.078125  , 248.05859375, 249.0390625 , 250.01953125,
        251.        ]),
 <BarContainer object of 256 artists>)
```

[image: the final histogram]

Comment: Note that you created a histogram of the red channel of the image. Also note that using `bins=256` creates quite some problems, it will create bins `0-0.98`,  `0.98-1.96`,   1`.96-2.94`, ... which don't align with your integer data values. Use `bins=np.arange(-0.5, 256, 1)` to get one bin per value.